# Conversion failed when I tried saving an image to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save image to database but the code throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '/Image/malzemeresim/kırmızı-biber.png' to data type int.

I have been try same code before different controllers but it does not cause an error.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult MalzemeEkle(Malzemeler m, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Tarif"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

        string sqlquery = "insert into [Malzeme].[dbo].[Malzemeler] (Malzeme,Mal_Resim,Cat_Id) values (@Malzeme,@Cat_Id,@Resim)";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);

        sqlconn.Open();

        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Malzeme", m.Malzeme);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cat_Id", m.Cat_Id);

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string imgpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Image/malzemeresim/"), filename);
            file.SaveAs(imgpath);
        }

        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resim","/Image/malzemeresim/" +file.FileName);

        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlconn.Close();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to save path of the file into db? or file itself?

Comment: The values are in the wrong order in the SQL: `values (@Malzeme,@Cat_Id,@Resim)` should be `values (@Malzeme,@Resim,@Cat_Id)`

Comment: @Simonare i'm trying to save path

Comment: @Haldo probably,I'm trying now

Comment: @Haldo thank you so much I didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of parameters matters when using `INSERT INTO [Table] (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3)`. The order of the values must match the order of the columns.

You should update your SQL to:

```
insert into [Malzeme].[dbo].[Malzemeler] 
    (Malzeme, Mal_Resim, Cat_Id) values (@Malzeme, @Resim, @Cat_Id)"
```

Answer (score 1):

the parameter order in your `insert` query is in wrong order. Change

```
insert into [Malzeme].[dbo].[Malzemeler] 
(Malzeme,Mal_Resim,Cat_Id) values (@Malzeme,@Cat_Id,@Resim)
```

to

```
insert into [Malzeme].[dbo].[Malzemeler] 
(Malzeme,Cat_Id,Mal_Resim) values (@Malzeme,@Cat_Id,@Resim)
```